# Java media frame work and netBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jmf

i installed jmf-2_1_1e-windows-i586 butit didn't include jar files and when i write java.media.*; in my code an error occurs that this library is not found !!? How to install java media frame work in net beans ?!!

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading [this](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jmf/2.1.1e/jmf-2_1_1e-alljava.zip) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR)
Extract the compressed file and inside `lib` folder you will the `jmf.jar`. Include `jmf.jar` in your project.